# How to make a video call using a ringtone when calling in React Native?

Tags: react-native, one-to-one, ringtone, videochat

I need to implement a video call in chat in React Native ,

Like when calling in messenger, whatsapp and duo .

I found some SDKs and APIs that implement the video chat like Agora.io , webRtc , and others but the

problem is that when someone calls the other there is no phone ring to alert him of a call ,

so what is the best way to implement the video call and ringing when receive a call ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Hi Maria Nabil, To implement ringtone feature when call arrive to any device, you can used push notification and play a ring tone in background when you receive incoming call notification through push notification and when user react on that stop playing ringtone. You can also try call kit feature in your app.